# Twitter Client with multiple account support Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, client, twitter

Did so far :-

1. Tried Birdie (installed using using deb file, current status - starts but not working, unable to uninstall as well.)
2. Turprial (installed, started well, but not accepting PIN - tried numerous times)
3. Corebird - Heard that it is not stable yet, couldn't find a trustworthy PPA or deb file. So skipped till I am sure of it.

PS : Using Friends, but looking for a client with support for multiple accounts and better interface. Something like TweetDeck.

Answer (score 3):

Corebird supports multiple accounts -

[image]

Corebird 0.9 is developed in GTK+3.12 and the Ubuntu 14.04 is based on GTK+3.10.

Therefore, the GNOME 3 and GNOME 3 Staging PPAs need to be added in order to satisty all the Corebird dependencies.

To install -

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntuhandbook1/corebird
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install corebird
```

Alternatively, you can download the `.deb` file [here](http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntuhandbook1/corebird/ubuntu/pool/main/c/corebird/corebird_0.9~trusty0-1_amd64.deb) and install it using `dpkg` -

```
sudo dpkg -i <filename>.deb
```

Comment: Thanks @Rohit Madhavan. I use latest Cinnamon on 14.o4. Also is Corebird stable enough ? PS: Just concerned as I intend to depend on it.

Comment: CoreBird is awesome. Nevertheless some people is facing the "transparent background" issue which seems to be solved by running corebird via Terminal with this command: LIBOVERLAY_SCROLLBAR=0 corebird. You can create an executable file inside your /usr/bin folder and include this command in order to invoke it in a single word command. Thank you very much for sharing.